# Quantlib 1.5 build

Tags: c++, boost, quantlib

Under CentOS 7, I am using

```
[idf@node2 QuantLib-1.5]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) (GCC) 
[idf@node2 QuantLib-1.5]$
```

Using Boost.1_58, I get the following error while build QL 1.5

```
Making all in math
make[4]: Entering directory `/mnt/gluster/Downloads/QuantLib-1.5/ql/experimental/math'
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../ql  -I../../.. -I../../..   -g -O2 -MT convolvedstudentt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/convolvedstudentt.Tpo -c -o convolvedstudentt.lo convolvedstudentt.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../ql -I../../.. -I../../.. -g -O2 -MT convolvedstudentt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/convolvedstudentt.Tpo -c convolvedstudentt.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/convolvedstudentt.o
convolvedstudentt.cpp: In member function 'QuantLib::Real QuantLib::InverseCumulativeBehrensFisher::operator()(QuantLib::Probability) const':
convolvedstudentt.cpp:194:29: error: call of overloaded 'bind(QuantLib::Probability (QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher::*)(QuantLib::Real) const, QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher&, boost::arg<1>&)' is ambiguous
                 distrib_, _1)), accuracy_, (xMin+xMax)/2., xMin, xMax);
                             ^
convolvedstudentt.cpp:194:29: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from convolvedstudentt.cpp:30:
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1602:5: note: boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type> boost::bind(F, A1, A2) [with R = double; F = double (QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher::*)(double) const; A1 = QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher; A2 = boost::arg<1>; typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher>, boost::arg<1> >]
     BOOST_BIND(F f, A1 a1, A2 a2)
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind_mf_cc.hpp:74:5: note: boost::_bi::bind_t<R, boost::_mfi::cmf1<R, T, A1>, typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type> boost::bind(R (T::*)(B1) const, A1, A2) [with R = double; T = QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher; B1 = double; A1 = QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher; A2 = boost::arg<1>; typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher>, boost::arg<1> >]
     BOOST_BIND(R (BOOST_BIND_MF_CC T::*f) (B1) const, A1 a1, A2 a2)
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind_mf_cc.hpp:96:5: note: boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2, boost::_mfi::cmf1<R, T, B1>, typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type> boost::bind(R (T::*)(B1) const, A1, A2) [with Rt2 = double; R = double; T = QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher; B1 = double; A1 = QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher; A2 = boost::arg<1>; typename boost::_bi::list_av_2<A1, A2>::type = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<QuantLib::CumulativeBehrensFisher>, boost::arg<1> >]
     BOOST_BIND(R (BOOST_BIND_MF_CC T::*f) (B1) const, A1 a1, A2 a2)
     ^
make[4]: *** [convolvedstudentt.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/mnt/gluster/Downloads/QuantLib-1.5/ql/experimental/math'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/gluster/Downloads/QuantLib-1.5/ql/experimental'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/gluster/Downloads/QuantLib-1.5/ql'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/gluster/Downloads/QuantLib-1.5/ql'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
[idf@node2 QuantLib-1.5]$
```

and

```
[idf@node2 math]$ make
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../ql  -I../../.. -I../../..   -g -O2 -MT convolvedstudentt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/convolvedstudentt.Tpo -c -o convolvedstudentt.lo convolvedstudentt.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../ql -I../../.. -I../../.. -g -O2 -MT convolvedstudentt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/convolvedstudentt.Tpo -c convolvedstudentt.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/convolvedstudentt.o
convolvedstudentt.cpp: In member function 'QuantLib::Real QuantLib::InverseCumulativeBehrensFisher::operator()(QuantLib::Probability) const':
convolvedstudentt.cpp:194:54: error: wrong type argument to unary minus
 -                &CumulativeBehrensFisher::operator (),
                                                      ^
convolvedstudentt.cpp:196:53: error: wrong type argument to unary plus
 +                &CumulativeBehrensFisher::operator(),
                                                     ^
make: *** [convolvedstudentt.lo] Error 1
[idf@node2 math]$
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [quantlib users mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.quantlib.user) and a few recent messages -- in short, Boost 1.58 (which came out after QuantLib 1.5) creates some issues so your best guess is probably to stick with Boost 1.57.

On the other hand if you want to stick with Boost 1.58, try [this patch](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/commit/659addb2400442b356b1c194bf331cdc8bbb3c1d).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the original problem. See the edited post for additional problems. Is there a way to turn off experimental?